# Why does Renge cosplay as Kisaragi Quon?

Tags: rahxephon, ouran-high-school-host-club

In episode 7 of *Ouran*, Renge cosplays (poorly) as Kisaragi Quon from *RahXephon*.

[image: left: Houshakuji Renge; right: Kisaragi Quon]

But why?

I suppose it could just be a throwaway reference, given that that *Ouran* and *RahXephon* are both Bones productions; I'm just wondering if there's any greater depth to it than that.

Answer (score 2):

In the designs created by Akihiro Yamada, that were adapted by Hiroki Kanno for the anime, Quon is depicted wearing clothes with a very French motif (e.g. parasol, beret).

[image: Quon illustration]

On the Vol.2 DVD release (used in France and Japan, but not in the initial U.S. and UK release), Yamada illustrated Quon wearing a frilly lace-trimmed dress and stockings, carrying a parasol for a goth loli look, which was inspired Old French Victorian style dresses.

[image: Quon v.2 cover]

The stereotypes mesh well with Renge, being a French "otaku."